Rest API endpoints for handling Sign in with Google
I am trying to implement a "Sign in with Google" flow, with a front-end in React and a back-end in python, using FastAPI. What I'm struggling to understand is independent of the specific technologies though.
After a lot of research, I'm still unsure of the way to go for implementing it. My main question is : Who handles the code and the token ?
I see multiple ways this could be done :
FIRST OPTION

You initialize the login with google from the front-end by sending the user to the specific Google URL.
The "redirect" URL specifies a URL from the front-end.
When the user hits that callback URL, containing the code, you exchange the code for a token with JavaScript.
When you get the token back, you finally send it to your backend for authentifying.

SECOND OPTION

You initialize the login with google from the front-end by sending a request to your backend, which returns the right URL to call.
The callback url is an endpoint from the server.
When that endpoint hits, the server gets the code, exchanges it for a token, signs in the user.
??? => The user is currently "on the server", how does it get back ? Do you just send a redirect from the server to your front ? If we do that, then only 1 front-end app can use this API, since the redirect is hardcoded in the back-end code. It might not be an issue, I will only develop a single front-end app for this API, but would this be ok ?

THIRD OPTION

You initialize the login with google from the front-end by sending the user to the specific Google URL.
The "redirect" URL specifies a URL from the front-end.
When the user hits that callback URL, containing the code, you then make a request to an endpoint from your backend, which handles the exchange of code/token and sends it back to you.

There might even be some more options, and I'm just left wondering which one is the way to go. I've been searching, and I'm left with more options/questions than answers.
I'd be glad to have an educated answer on this topic.
